# PHP Laravel @include javascript variable not found

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-4

Laravel how o can use javascript variables from include file? I try this below example but variable not found..

**includeFile.blade.php**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var myMar = "Hello world";
    });
</script>
```

**default.blade.php**

```
@include('layouts.includeFile')

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert(myVar); //Here myVar is undefined
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `myMar` is private in `includeFile.blade.php`. Try something like this

**includeFile.blade.php**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var myMar = "Hello world";
        @yield('doc_ready')
    });
</script>
```

**default.blade.php**

```
@extends('includeFile')
@section('doc_ready')
    alert(myVar); //Here myVar is defined
@stop
```

Or just remove `var`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        myMar = "Hello world";
    });
</script>
```

And also you have typo in includeFile it is `myMar` and in default it is `myVar`

Answer (score 3):

**myVar** must be declared outside the function to be visible in another functions

**includeFile.blade.php**

```
<script>
    var myVar; // Create global variable
    $(document).ready(function () {
        myVar = "Hello world";
    });
</script>
```

**default.blade.php**

```
@include('layouts.includeFile')

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert(myVar);
    });
</script>
```